# Can i retrieve microseconds or very accurate milliseconds on c++ on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, time, timer

So I made a game loop that uses `SDL_Delay` function to cap the `frames per second`, it look like this:

```
//While the user hasn't qui

while( stateID != STATE_EXIT )
{
    //Start the frame timer
    fps.start();

    //Do state event handling
    currentState->handle_events();

    //Do state logic
    currentState->logic();

    //Change state if needed
    change_state();

    //Do state rendering
    currentState->render();

    //Update the screen
    if( SDL_Flip( screen ) == -1 )
    {
        return 1;    
    }

    //Cap the frame rate
    if( fps.get_ticks() < 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND )
    {
        SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND ) - fps.get_ticks() );
    }
}
```

So when I run my games on `60 frames per second` (which is the "eye cap" I assume) I can still see laggy type of motion, meaning i see the frames appearing independently causing unsmooth motion.
This is because apparently `SDL_Delay` function is not too accurate, causing `+,- 15 milliseconds` or something difference between frames greater than whatever I want it to be.
(all these are just my assumptions)

so I am just searching fo a good and accurate timer that will help me with this problem.

any suggestions?

Comment: `QueryPerformanceCounter` is good for that, IIRC. C++11 also has the `<chrono>` header, but I don't think it's quite as good.

Comment: I have some public domain code that might help too: https://github.com/TheBuzzSaw/DateTimePlusPlus/blob/master/Win32Time.cpp

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a similar question in [How to make thread sleep less than a millisecond on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85122/sleep-less-than-one-millisecond)

But as a game programmer myself, I don't rely on sleep functions to manage frame-rate (the parameter they take is just a *minimum*). I just draw stuff on screen as fast as I can. I have a bunch of function calls in my game loop, and then I keep track of how often I'm calling them. For instance, I check input quite often (1000x/second) to make the game more responsive, but I don't check the network inbox more than 100x/second.

For example:

```
#define NW_CHECK_INTERVAL    10
#define INPUT_CHECK_INTERVAL  1
uint32_t last_nw_check = 0, last_input_check = 0;

while (game_running) {
    uint32_t now = SDL_GetTicks();

    if (now - last_nw_check > NW_CHECK_INTERVAL) {
        check_network();
        last_nw_check = now;
    }

    if (now - last_input_check > INPUT_CHECK_INTERVAL) {
        check_input();
        last_input_check = now;
    }

    check_video();

    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: I don't know why i have never thought of writing my loops this way, but there is one thing i don't understand. If this was to yield a call to check_input() 1000x/sec, doesn't this mean that the while(game_running) loop must execute at least with the same speed? To me it seems you can only get the granularity equal to the frame rate with this method. 60 FPS graphics -> check_input() maximum 60x/sec. I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small wait function I had created for timing midi sequences using `QueryPerformanceCounter`:

```
void wait(int waitTime) {
    LARGE_INTEGER time1, time2, freq;

    if(waitTime == 0)
        return;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&time1);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

    do {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&time2);
    } while((time2.QuadPart - time1.QuadPart) * 1000000ll / freq.QuadPart < waitTime);
}
```

To convert ticks to microseconds, calculate the difference in ticks, multiply by 1,000,000 (microseconds/second) and divide by the frequency of ticks per second.

Note that some things may throw this off, for instance the precision of the high-resolution counter is not likely to be down to a single microsecond. For example, if you want to wait 10 microseconds and the precision/frequency is one tick every 6 microseconds, your 10 microsecond wait will actually be no less than 12 microseconds. Again, this frequency is system dependent and will vary from system to system.

Also, Windows is not a real-time operating system. A process may be preempted at any time and it is up to Windows to decide when the process is rescheduled. The application may be preempted in the middle of this function and not restarted again until long after the expected wait time has elapsed. There really isn't much you can do about it but you'll probably never notice it if it happens.

Answer (score 2):

Use the QueryPerformanceCounter / Frequency for that.

```
LARGE_INTEGER start, end, tps; //tps = ticks per second
QueryPerformanceFrequency( &tps );
QueryPerformanceCounter( &start );
QueryPerformanceCounter( &end );
int usPassed = (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) * 1000000 / tps.QuadPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

60 fame per second is just the frequency of power in US (50 in Europe, Africa and Asia are somehow mixed) and is the frequency of video refreshing for hardware comfortable reasons (It can be an integer multiple on more sophisticated monitors). It was a mandatory constrains for CRT dispaly, and it is still a comfortable reference for LCD (that's how frequently the frame buffer is uploaded to the display)

The eye-cap is no more than 20-25 fps - not to be confused with retina persistency, that's about one-half - and that's why TV interlace two squares upon every refresh.

independently on the timing accuracy, whatever hardware device cannot be updated during its buffer-scan (otherwise the image changes while it is shown, resulting in half-drawn broken frames), hence, if you go faster than one half of the device refresh you are queued behind it and forced to wait for it.

60 fps in a game loop serves only to help CPU manufacturers to sell new faster CPUs. Slow down under 25 and everything will look more fluid.

Answer (score 0):

SDL_Delay:

`This function waits a specified number of milliseconds before returning. It waits at least the specified time, but possible longer due to OS scheduling. The delay granularity is at least 10 ms. Some platforms have shorter clock ticks but this is the most common.`

The actual delays observed with this function depend on OS settings. I'd suggest to look into the
[Mutimedia Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, particulary into the [timeBeginPeriod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function, to adapt the interrupt frequency to your requirements.

[Obtaining and Setting Timer Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows an example how to change the interrupt period to about 1ms. This way you don't have the 15ms hickup anymore. *BTW: Eye-catch period is about 40ms.*

Obtaining fixed period timing can also be addressed by [Waitable Timer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But the use of mutimedia timers is mandatory to obtain decent resolution, no matter what.

Using other tools to improve the timing capabilities is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11537483/1504523).